# Cannot destructure property 'desks' of '(0 , _react.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I try to mock DeskContext for having desks and checkIfUserPresent when useContext is called. But I have this error:

```
Cannot destructure property 'desks' of '(0 , _react.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'desks' of '(0 , _react.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined.
```

This is when I run this test:

```
it('It should have a reserved button because user is not present', () => {
render(<Desk desk={deskWithNoReservation} dateOfConsultation={dateInTheFuture()}/>)

        const buttonElement = screen.getByText('Réserver')
    
        expect(buttonElement).toBeInTheDocument()
    })
```

Here is my code:

```
...
jest.mock('../context/DeskContext', () => ({
DeskContext:{
   desks: [{
      deskNumber: 11,
      reservation: "mocked name"
   }],
   checkIfUserPresent: () => {
      return false
   },
}
}))

jest.mock('./ModalWindow', () => ({ ModalWindow: () => 'Réserver' }));

describe('Test for Desk component', () => {

    it('It should have a reserved button because user is not present', () => {
        render(<Desk desk={deskWithNoReservation} dateOfConsultation={dateInTheFuture()}/>)
    
        const buttonElement = screen.getByText("Réserver")
    
        expect(buttonElement).toBeInTheDocument()
    })

...
```

In my class 'DeskComponent', this is the line (the first one of the component) that cause the error:
"const {desks, checkIfUserPresent} = useContext<any>(DeskContext)"

Here is DeskContext class:

```
import { createContext } from "react"

export const DeskContext = createContext({})
```

Do you know what to do to define desks and checkIfUserSPResent for further code?
Thanks.

To define desks and checkIfUserSPResent for passing the test?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the provider in the render and no need to mock, it's working!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the desk object with the provider in the render, so yours would be something like

```
    render(<DeskProvider><Desk desk={deskWithNoReservation} dateOfConsultation={dateInTheFuture()}/><DeskProvider/>)
```